# Is the answer to the given question right

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $p\ge 5$ is a prime show that $\Bbb Z_p\times \Bbb Z_p$ has at least $p$ subgroups of order $p$.

I think the question is false.If I take $p=5$ then $\Bbb Z_5\times Z_5$ has only $4$ subgroups viz $\Bbb Z_5 \times Z_5,\{0\}\times \Bbb Z_5,\{0\}\times\{0\}.$

Am I right?Please let me know.

Comment: Not sure why the $p\geq 5$ part is there. The number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ is always $p+3$ for any prime $p$ (you are probably forgetting all the diagonal subgroups).

Answer (score 1):

The statement is correct (though the hypothesis that $p\geq 5$ is unnecessary).  Here's one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ that you're missing: $\{(a,a):a\in\mathbb{Z}_5\}$.  I'll let you check that this really is a subgroup.  To find more subgroups, you might try starting with a random element of $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ and thinking about what subgroup it generates.